# How to lock to desired axis permanently in edit mode

Tags: edit-mode

Is there a way in edit mode to lock tweaks to the desired axis permanently? I'd like to tweak a couple of vertices consecutively without pressing "y" or whatever all the time invoking the tweak (grab, or simple grab after selecting the vert).

Thank you,

Mihály

Comment: I had this exact thought today, none of the answers satisfy my desire to have a toggle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could setup a specific hotkey for this.

In the *User Preferences > Input > 3D View* add a new operator `transform.translate` assign whichever available key combination you want, then in the options below tick *Constraint > Y*

Whenever you press that key combination it will automatically invoke the move command constrained to the desired axis.

If you don't want a different hotkey you can set this temporarily or permanently  in the existing <kbd>G</kbd> hotkey.

You may also use the *Move* tool from the toolbar and use the Transfrom gizmo by hovering the desired axis effectively constraining to that vector.

Comment: @MihályVarju if this answer is great, then consider to vote for it or select as the best answer. :)

Comment: @Duarte where can I find the list of operator admitted like "transform.translate" for Blender?

Comment: The Python console provides autocomplete. You can look at the available operators for any context in the keymap list, or you can [look in the documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.html?highlight=bpy%20ops%20view_3d) or you can see [what is used in the UI from the tooltips](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164006/how-can-i-find-the-python-triggered-by-the-gui/164008#164008)

Answer (score 5):

If you're using hotkeys to translate your vertices, the fastest way to work is to use the middle-click shortcut:

1. Press <kbd>G</kbd> to begin your grab operation and begin moving your selection roughly along the axis you want to lock to.
2. Now, middle-click and you'll be locked to that axis.

Alternatively, you can hold the middle mouse button down (again, while still in the Grab operation) and you'll see lock guides in the 3D View. While still holding the middle mouse button, you can drag your selection to lock to one of these axes. When you release the middle mouse button, the lock remains in place.

Both methods also work with the right-click-and-drag "tweak mode" way of initiating the Grab operator.

Comment: Thank you Fweeb. But my problem is when I want to edit a new vert, each time I'm selecting a new vert I have to go trough the steps. It would be great if Blender could retain the last lock. This way the only thing I have to do is to select my newly selected vert and grab. If there were any icon representing the x - y - z axes, and if you could push them, this would restrain all translation, tweak to the selected axis (axes), until you disable these.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to press any buttons to make the transformations just use the ***manipulator tool***. Please see [the manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/manipulators.html) for more details.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I can help anyone because the question is very old but I know what you mean and you can do it easily in the N menu by pressing the lock right next to the transformation values and the axis will be locked until you unlock it.[image]

Comment: The questions ask to lock movement in edit mode and not object mode.