# How can i find the python triggered by the GUI?

Tags: python, scripting, gltf

I want to fully automatize some of my blender processes, an i run into a lot of problems not finding the correct commands, not using the correct args...

Can i just "see" in a log somewhere what were the commands blender ran ?

To be very precise, i want to load a gltf file, and export it to stl.

No problem through the gui, but i'm stuck with that bit of code :

```
import bpy
import sys
import os

file = open(r"C:\Users\theo1\Documents\GitHub\Hackathon2020\map&mapdata\mini.gltf")

bpy.ops.import_scene.gltf(file)
bpy.ops.export_mesh.stl(filePath=r"C:\Users\theo1\Documents\GitHub\Hackathon2020\map&mapdata\mini.stl")
```

Which gives me this :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\theo1\Desktop\impExp.py", line 7, in <module>
    bpy.ops.import_scene.gltf(file)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.81\2.81\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 198, in __call__
    C_dict, C_exec, C_undo = BPyOpsSubModOp._parse_args(args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.81\2.81\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 151, in _parse_args
    raise ValueError("1-3 args execution context is supported")
ValueError: 1-3 args execution context is supported
```

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [API documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/index.html) should be your primary reference when implementing Python scripts for Blender.

Additionally you can enable the *Python Tooltips* and *Developer Extras* in the preferences (*Edit > Preferences > Interface > Display*).

[image: Preferences]

The *Python Tooltips* will be displayed when hovering over a UI element with your mouse and show what Python command would be executed when interacting with it. The *Developer Extras* add helpful options such as *Edit Source* or *Online Python Reference* to the context menu (<kbd>RMB</kbd>).

[image: Python Tooltip]

[image: Online Python Reference]

---

Using the references provided above it's fairly easy to see why your script doesn't work properly.

[`bpy.ops.import_scene.gltf()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.import_scene.html#bpy.ops.import_scene.gltf) expects a file path as argument, not a file object. Therefore you shouldn't use [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) at all. Instead pass the file path as named argument:

```
bpy.ops.import_scene.gltf(filepath="/path/to/your/file")
```

Comment: This os exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much